# Outside light fixture keeps tripping the breaker

Tags: circuit-breaker

I replaced an outdoor light fixture and when I turn on the switch the breaker trips. The wiring is correct and secure. There are two light switches in the garage. The one on the right controls the inside garage lights and supplies power to the switch next to it which only controls the outside light. The switches look intact and in good condition. How do I determine what the source of the problem is?

Comment: If the breaker trips right when you turn on the switch, then there is a short.  Either a ground wire touching the switch hot(why some switches have tape wrap around them) or there is a short somewhere between the switch and light.

Comment: ↑ If  the only change is the fixture, that would be the first place to check…

Comment: Pictures of wiring in fixture box and switch box would help. Fits the breaker have a TEST button?

Comment: Generally, when you change a fixture and the breaker trips when you turn it on, asserting that the wiring is **correct** is often in error. I mean, it *could* be a defective fixture, but 999 times out of 1000 it's user error.